# x coordinates resets after changing speed?

Tags: java, libgdx

I wanted to change the speed of a soldier when he enters a barbed wire texture. 
Since I have multiple soldiers and multiple barbed wires I just iterate with two for-loops through all of them.

```
for(int j = entityWalkingRightArray.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  final entity_walking_right entity_walking_right = entityWalkingRightArray.get(j);
  for(int i = barbedWireArray.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    final barbedWire wire = barbedWireArray.get(i);
    //Checks if the entity is inside the barbed wire
    if(  entity_walking_right.getX() >= wire.getX() 
      && entity_walking_right.getX() <= wire.getX() + wire.getWidth() 
      && entity_walking_right.getY() >= wire.getY() 
      && entity_walking_right.getY() <= wire.getY() + wire.getHeight()) {

      entity_walking_right.changeSpeed();
    } else {
      //entity_walking_right.changeSpeed2();
    }
  }
}
```

In the class of the soldier the speed is set to 500 and the positionX is set to 200 when he is first created. I also have these two functions:

```
public void changeSpeed(){
    speed = 50;
}

public void changeSpeed2(){
    speed = 500;
}
```

In the `render()` function of the soldier's class the position is determined.

```
runningTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
positionX = speed * runningTime;
```

When he now enters the barbed wire and the speed is set to 50 then the positionX changes to 200 and he runs with a speed of 50. When I activate `entity_walking_right.changeSpeed2();` then he runs with normal speed (500) through the barbed wire and starts blinking rapidly while another version which also blinks rapidly on positionX 200 with a speed of 50. I looked at the positionX value and he just "teleports" again and again between those two positions. When the "500 speed version" of him reaches the end of the barbed wire everything is normal again. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is what is responsible for making your soldier blink/teleport:

```
runningTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
positionX = speed * runningTime;
```

Once the soldier hits the barb wire, it will change speed every frame: frame 1 it will go slow because it hits the barb wire, so the `positionX = speed * runningTime;` will then bring him to an earlier position, frame 2 "ah! I'm no longer in the barb wire, they're far up ahead, so let's go fast again!", so the speed is now fast, and so this line will make it go straight into the barb wire again.

We generally don't move entities based on "running time", as you're using; we move them based only on the delta time and their speed/acceleration.

What you want is probably something like this:

```
positionX += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Instead of setting the position based on the total running time, you move the entity based on what happened since last frame. This will take their new speed into consideration, with their current position.